# Gas stove issue

Tags: repair, stove

Anyone handy with gas stoves? Our burners stopped igniting (no clicking) so we opened up the top of the stove to check the spark module and one of the cords had somehow come disconnected. Plugged back in and the igniters clicked. I cleaned all the igniters and burners/caps and let dry. The igniters click and spark when the stove top is open but as soon as I close it to replace the burners/caps/grates, the click becomes muted and no more spark. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Just a guess.  The top of the stove is touching a wire and shorting it out.  Would check the wires carefully to see if any insulation is broken or looks like it is dented/squeezed.  It might be very minor and need a very close look.

Comment: What's the make and  model number of the stove?